# Why date from data base dont show on home.html Python Django

Tags: html, django, database, django-models, django-views

The problem is that date from database that i have created doesnt show on my html page and i dont understand what is the problem maybe i connected something wrong
models.py

```
from django.db import models


class table_1(models.Model):
    datetime = models.DateField()
    machine_1 = models.IntegerField()
    machine_2 = models.IntegerField()
    dryer = models.IntegerField()
    machine_1_time = models.TimeField()
    machine_2_time = models.TimeField()
    dryer_time = models.TimeField()

    def __int__(self):
        return self.title
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'data',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '1221',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<h2>1{{ tablet.machine_1_time }}</h2>

   {{ mytable.machine_1 }}

{% for item in tablet %}
    <h3>{{ item.datetime }}</h3>
    <!-- Выведите другие поля модели -->
{% endfor %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import table_1

def home(request):
    tablet = table_1.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'table/home.html', {' tablet':  tablet})
```

When i runserver there is no data shown at all

machine_data.sql

```
create table machine_dara (
    datetime DATE,
    machine_1 INT,
    machine_2 INT,
    dryer INT,
    machine_1_time INT,
    machine_2_time INT,
    dryer_time INT
);
insert into machine_dara (datetime, machine_1, machine_2, dryer, machine_1_time, machine_2_time, dryer_time) values ('2022-12-31', 55, 77, 35, 84, 91, 63);
insert into machine_dara (datetime, machine_1, machine_2, dryer, machine_1_time, machine_2_time, dryer_time) values ('2023-01-14', 67, 69, 79, 80, 50, 64);
insert into machine_dara (datetime, machine_1, machine_2, dryer, machine_1_time, machine_2_time, dryer_time) values ('2023-01-13', 30, 8, 14, 71, 5, 19);
insert into machine_dara (datetime, machine_1, machine_2, dryer, machine_1_time, machine_2_time, dryer_time) values ('2022-12-16', 21, 35, 96, 30, 28, 26); ........
```

Give me advice what should I do pls

Comment: Run this command in terminal `python manage.py shell ` and then the same query for fetching the same data from DB `table_1.objects.all()`. If no data is found then recheck if you are using same DB in which you are inserting data.

Comment: You insert your data into a table named `machine_data`. Django names its managed tables like `<app>_<model lowercased>`. That it why your django model has no data.

Comment: @MubasharJaved here what it says >>> table_1.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>